# How to remove text from FileUpload using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have this FileUpload control.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUp1" runat="server"/>
```

Code below is what i used but not working. When I try `.val("")` to a TextBox, it is fine.

```
$('#<%=FileUp1.ClientID %>').val("");
```

Comment: What are you trying to set?

Comment: I try your code in firefox and it's work.

Comment: oh sorry i forgot to mention that i am using IE9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try This may be.

```
//For IE
$("#control").replaceWith($("#control").clone(true));
//For other browsers
$("#control").val("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn").click(function () {
            $('#FileUp1').val("");
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUp1" runat="server"/>
<asp:Button ID="btn" runat="server" Text="Click Me" />
```